# header("Location: example.php"); not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, redirect

can anyone tell me why my header redirection does not work?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
include('includes/link.php');
include('includes/time_stamp.php');

session_start();

$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];

$path = "uploads/";
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg");
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name);

$time=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, id_fk, ip,created) VALUES ('$actual_image_name', '$id', '$ip','$time')");

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your script do the database insert correctly?

Comment: Yes, the database insert shows up.

Comment: So what do you see on screen when you execute this script?

Comment: Wrap the `mysql_query` in a condition first to even check if it executes or dies with an exception before the redirect.

Comment: The page is just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header must be the first thing **sent** to the browser (it doesn't *have* to be on top though). In your case, put it at the beginning of your PHP script and make sure there are no white spaces before the opening tag.

Comment: Thats only half true. You have to send it to the browser first, yes, but you dont have to put it on top of the php script. You just have to make sure there is no other output (like echo, print, etc.) before your send the headers.

Comment: I want the the redirection to happen after the mysql insert. Putting it at the top does redirect. Thanks though.

Comment: The MySQL insert will be executed anyways. I didn't say it must be put first, but suggested putting it on the top to avoid complications with any output that might be caused by secondary functions.

Comment: Edited since some of you guys seem to be intentionally misreading my statement. I never said it **has** to be on top of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not echoed anything before `header("Location: index.php");` or there no whitespaces or try using

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='index.php'</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still see just white page, you have to echo the error .

With this blow code, if the `mysql_query` works, then the location will be changed.

Otherwise, you will see error message.

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
include('includes/link.php');
include('includes/time_stamp.php');
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$path = "uploads/";
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg");
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name);
$time=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sq = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, id_fk, ip,created) VALUES ('$actual_image_name', '$id', '$ip','$time')");
if ($sq) {
header("Location: index.php");
}
else {
    echo "SQL Error.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it's better to debug line-by-line.

**Case 1**

Can you enable error reporting on the top of your file so that you can see if there are any error messages.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );

include('includes/connect.php');
include('includes/link.php');
include('includes/time_stamp.php');
?>
```

If there are no errors, proceed to step 2.

**Case 2**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );

include('includes/connect.php');
include('includes/link.php');
include('includes/time_stamp.php');

header( 'Location: index.php' );
exit(1); // always put this after header call to stop script execution.

// comment every thing below it.
?>
```

If the above works, there might be an error in your query.

Answer (score 0):

if the mysql_query() function call is correct, try using output buffering before sending the header to the browser for redirection